# iOS 設定情報の言語取得、国情報取得方法

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift2

設定画面の言語、国の情報を取得したいのですが、

ios9系だと

NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first 
を使うと、
「ja-JP」と出力されます。

ios8以下だと、
　「ja」と出力されます。

欲しい情報としては、「ja-JP」なのですが、ios8以下ではどのように「言語ー国」
を取得できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

別々に取り出して、必要に応じてつなげれば良いのではないでしょうか?

```
        let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let languageCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String //->ja
        let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String //->JP
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSLocale.preferredLanguages()`はもともと **言語コード** を返すAPIですので、デバイスの言語と地域の設定を取得する場合は、`NSLocale.currentLocale()`の方がより適切です。

iOS8までとiOS9以降での言語コードの扱い変化については、[Technical Note TN2418](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2418/_index.html)を参照してみてください。

対して、`currentLocale()`は端末のロケール設定を取得するものですので、iOS8以前でも一貫して言語と地域を取得できます。

```
NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier
```

を用いると、`ja_JP`が取得できます。ハイフンではなくアンダーバーで結合されています。